# Normal bundle with Complete intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

In general case, consider $X$ be a smooth complex manifold and $S = D_{1} \cap D_{2} \subset X$ be a complete intersection. Is there a relation beetween normal bundle of S, denoted by $N_{S/X}$, and the normal bundle of each hypersurface $D_{i}$ for $i=1,2$?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94214/elementary-exact-sequence-of-normal-sheaves